# Arduino & ESP8266 HTTP GET Response handling

Tags: c, arduino, http-get, esp8266

I'm successfully connecting my server but I can't handle the response data. esp8266.find("+PID,") doesn't work. My loop code is below:

```
void loop() {
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\""; //make this command: AT+CPISTART="TCP","192.168.88.35",80
  cmd += DST_IP;
  cmd += "\",80\r\n";
  esp8266.print(cmd);
  //wait a little while for 'Linked'
  delay(3000);

  //This is our HTTP GET Request change to the page and server you want to load.
  cmd = "GET /~atolye/wifiModule.php?id=123 HTTP/1.0\r\n";
  cmd += "Host: 159.122.115.70\r\n\r\n";
  esp8266.print("AT+CIPSEND=63\r\n");
  if(esp8266.find(">")) {
    //Send our http GET request
    Serial.println("SENDING THE REQUEST");
    esp8266.print(cmd);
    if(esp8266.find("+IPD,")) {
      Serial.println("\r\nIPD FOUND");
      if(esp8266.find("\"1")) {
        int value = esp8266.read()-48;
        Serial.println("\r\nVALUE FOUND");
        Serial.println(value);
        esp8266.println(value);
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("\r\n!! IPD NOT FOUND");
    }
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("\r\nERROR > DOESN'T EXIST");
  //Something didn't work...
    esp8266.print("AT+CIPCLOSE\r\n");
  }

}
```

**And this is the output:** As you can notice, IPD NOT FOUND executes before RESPONSE arrives. What should I do to catch that data? Thanks in advance.

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","159.122.115.70",80

CONNECT

OK
SENDING THE REQUEST

!! IPD NOT FOUND
START="TCP","159.122.115.70",80

busy s...

Recv 103 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,205:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2016 08:33:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

"12"CLOSED
```

Comment: You probably have to wait for the received data. I don't know the library, but there may be some function like `dataAvailable` you could call. Could you link to the documentation of the library?

Comment: I'm using only SofwareSerial.h. I don't know where to wait for my data. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The request takes some time. I was not sure how `Serial.find` works, some googling shows that it does indeed wait for data, but has a timeout of 1000 ms. If the setup of your connection and waiting for the answer from the server takes more time than 1000 ms, this could be the reason.

Comment: I will debug further using delay functions. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @KarstenKoop solved, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not about response time. Assume there is a TCP connection opened via AT+CIPSTART, and a request which is 42 chars long, as shown below:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 77.223.129.195\r\n
```

Before executing one should set CIPSEND to char count. Problem is, \r\n *are counted as 1 byte each, shouldn't be counted 2 chars.* Request consists of 4 chars 42-4 = 38.

```
AT+CIPSEND=38\r\n
```

Excluding 2 bytes solved the problem and successfully displayed before the code checks if there are any "+PID,"s.

Comment: The string `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 77.223.129.195\r\n` is not 42 chars long but 38 (`\r` and `\n` each are one char only)

Comment: Oh you meant 40 chars. Correct!

Comment: No, you have a total of 4 `\r` or `\n`. I'd guess your explanation is wrong, your character count was just off

Comment: @KarstenKoop you can post as an answer. Thanks again.